# Jsch throwing End of file Exception

Tags: java, ftp, sftp, jsch

This happens on some files but not on others.

```
1: End of file
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._stat(ChannelSftp.java:2198)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1294)
        at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.get(ChannelSftp.java:1266)
```

The code is simple:

```
        jsch.addIdentity("privateKeyFromOdin", sftpPrivateKey, null, null);
        session = jsch.getSession(SFTPUSER, SFTPHOST, SFTPPORT);
        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();
        Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

        Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> ls = channelSftp.ls(".");
        for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry : ls) {
                String fileName = entry.getFilename();
                encryptedStream = channelSftp.get(fileName);//Exception thrown here
        }
```

What's even more odd is that this used to work well. But I don't know what changed.

Comment: Can you download those files with some standalone SFTP client, like WinSCP? Show us its verbose log file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes I can

Comment: So again, show its log file, using scripting with `get /path/file` command (this will make WinSCP use the same SFTP requests as JSch).

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. I'm calling sftp from bash then get on the file that work.

Comment: OK, but `sftp` may not use the "stat" request. So it's not comparable to JSch. And it definitely cannot log the requests.

Comment: And did you try using an absolute path?

Comment: Exactly and I don't have any other way to do it. Also what I noticed is that when the file size is small it works anything > 150 k doesn't

Comment: Regarding the path the file is the root sftp home path I don't cd anywhere

Comment: I do not think your question is answerable unless you provide us more information.

Comment: Not sure if this is still required, but I got similar error and seems that it was due to inputstream not closed. After closing the inputstream this error got fixed for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue, I was not closing inputStream returned by each
"channelSftp.get(fileName)" call,
try closing inputStream